how to inherit from tkinter
I see two methods for using the tkinter module with python classes.

the first method uses the super() method.
the second method does not.

So the example code looks like this:
import tkinter as tk


class MyClass(tk.Tk):
    ''' class using super '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('class using super')
        self.mainloop()
        
        return
    
        


class MyOhterClass:
    ''' class that does not use super '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title('class NOT using super')
        self.win.mainloop()

        return
    
    
# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    app_1 = MyClass()
    app_2 = MyOhterClass()


Both of the classes work.
It looks like i can achieve exactly the same with both (as far as i can tell). The only difference being self compared to self.win for creation of the actual tkinter window.
But which of the two class methods is preferable (if any) ?

The return statement isn't necessary. As written, app_1 and app_2 will hold no meaningful value since the instance of each class will be destroyed before they return. I would choose the first approach MyClass.

Btw .mainloop() blocks code execution until all of the tk.Tk windows are closed so I don't recommend putting it in the __init__ method.  As for your question, it depends on what you are doing and how much you know about tkinter. Using the first approach, it's easier to make bigger widgets by inheriting from tk.Frame but you might accidentally overwrite a tkinter method without realising. The second approach is better if you are starting with OOP because it's more intuitive but can sometimes lead to bad design patterns. I recommend using both and picking your favourite.

You may be able to find more help if you know the appropriate terms for the two techniques you show. MyClass demonstrates "inheritance", while MyOhterClass (which is spelled incorrectly, by the way) demonstrates "composition". Both have roles to play in programming and OOP design.

Either is correct, however, personally, I prefer the first method due to the ease of use

@TheLizzard,  that's what i thought. surely at risk of overwriting a Tkinter method with the first class.   Noted on the Reutrns...

@Blckknght,  i never thought of it as "inheritance" or "composition". that is interesting... which is the better approach though or are they just different use cases ?

@DL they are different use cases. Even if you overwrite a tkinter method, unless it's used (probably not) it wouldn't be a problem. I can't think of a instance where it has been a problem for me. This question is similar to yours.

@TheLizzard,  the wiki link comp or inherit explains it really well. Basically, if extending on a class, then inherit, otherwise compose.  In the case of this question, the second method is preferable. Your help comments were very insightful - thanks.

So, your first method is called "inheritance", the second one, where you have the tkinter element as an attribute in your class is called "composition".
Despite the majority of documentation and tutorials doing it the first way, inheriting tkinter (or other GUI toolkits for that matter) and working from there, I consider composition a quite superior approach and easier to work with.
I´d say the inheriting trend is like an "accent" of languages which lack expressiveness with non-class related code, or maybe a reminescent of OOP hype in the early 1990s.
The cold facts is that inheriting from a tkinter class will give your subclass a namespace with hundreds of names (265 attributes for a tkinter.Tk class in my Python 3.12 build), any of which can clash with what you intend to do with your app.
If you search the web for "composition vs inheritance" you should find quite a few articles detailing the pros and cons of each approach.
